# How to implement content search in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, search, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement the content serch in iPhone using UISearchBar my code is as below.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)searchText {
    if([tableData count])
        [tableData removeAllObjects];

    //dataArray contains array of strings
         //tableData should containg arrow of strings as a serch result

    NSRange range = {0, [searchText length]};

    for(int i=0; i<[dataArray count]; ++i)
    {
        NSString *name = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if([name compare:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:range] == NSOrderedSame)
            [tableData addObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    [theTableView reloadData];
}
```

I am taking `dataArray` as a source of strings and then I want to search some content in each strings and then I need to store those strings which contains the search text, in the `tableData` array.

Write now I am getting only those strings as a search result in the starting text is matching as if in  the `dataArray` there are 3 objects 1. India, 2. China, 3. America and I am serching "in" then it should show India and China both but it showing only India because "In" is starting content of India.

Please suggest me how to achieve the required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To seach anywhere in the string you need to check the whole string to see if the searchTest appears anywhere:

```
NSRange titleResultsRange = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
    [tableData addObject:name]; // or [tableData addObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```